# Clipboard upload SharePoint 2010 multiple files

Tags: sharepoint-server, file-upload, file, ie

In our company we are looking for a component what allow copied physical files on disk can be pasted on web browser SharePoint 2010.

We have researched about it and everything point to use ActiveXObject, as a matter a fact, this must be only IE solution and it does not matter, here it is an intranet though.

If someone knows some component that can help us, thanks in advance, meanwhile I am trying to make some code but it has not been possible for me to get any reference of the name of the file copied in the system via clipboard. What I have been able to do is to get in the browser some text copied to clipboard, but in none case name's files or whatever we need.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the "Open in Explorer" feature is your best bet. Go to the target library, `click the "Library" tab`, and `click "Open in Explorer"` (only works in 32 bit IE). This will make the library look like a regular windows folder, from there you can copy and paste files in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the upload multiple files option, you can drag and drop files from your workstation into the browser and upload them.

[image: dragondrop]